# Reverting remote branch through PR to a specific commit

Tags: git, github, git-revert

Basically I have a remote master branch that I do not have direct push access to. I've identified a commit say x commits ago that I want to revert the remote branch to. Is there a simple way to do this without having to revert all the previous commits before x?

I've attempted:

```
git checkout -b A_DEV_BRANCH
git reset --hard COMMIT_SHA_X
git add .
git push origin A_DEV_BRANCH
```

But that reports 0 changes through the pull request, and doesn't appear to remove the commits since X, feel like I might be missing something simple here?

Comment: There are a bunch of phrases in this question (and your corresponding answer) that are confusing. You can't "revert *to* a commit". You either "*reset to* a commit", or you "*revert a* specific commit (or set of commits)". If you want to "reset to" a commit without using "reset", you'd have to revert all commits *after* that commit (not *before*). Your answer is also confusing because the question implies you wish to reset back (or revert all commits after), but your answer just does a single revert.

Comment: Regardless of whether you intended to "reset" or "revert", I think if the question was clearer, then it would very likely be a duplicate, since there are multiple questions about reset vs revert, and when to use each.

Comment: @TTT I'm almost sure this question would be a duplicate too, but I couldn't find anyone asking it in the same 'flavour'. I think the question actually demonstrates my misunderstanding of how git works and perhaps it's better this question and corresponding answer is deleted (it might serve only to confuse future readers).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this was to track down the specific commit (y) that results in x being present in the remote branch then revert it using `git revert y` and committing the result back to master.

To do what I wanted to do is possible using `git reset` but would involve re-writing history and potentially causing problems for people who based their work off of in between commits to the remote.